# How to put a function as an argument with unspecified sub arguments in C?

Tags: c, function, arguments

I am trying to make a function, which will execute a function with the provided sub arguments in C. Like:

```
int function(void (*func)(), ...) // add as many arguments you want for 'func()'
{
    va_list ptr;

    ...

    func(sub_arguments) // the '...'
}

void *abc(int a) { ... }
void *one(int b, int c) { ... }

int main()
{
   function(abc, 73);
   function(one, 9, 84);
}
```

Now, is there a way to somehow make a variable list and add it as the arguments and execute it? If so, how?

I know I phrased the question in a very difficult way, but I just don't get how to do this.

Comment: While this is possible, please note that doing it this way restricts compiler from checking for mistakes, and your function calls are very inefficient. You should try to avoid vararg functions as much as possible.

Comment: @user694733 That's probably the right thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want to look into C++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either extract each argument in `function()` and make the relevant call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void abc(int a) {
    printf("abc(%d)\n", a);
}

void one(int b, int c) {
    printf("one(%d,%d)\n", b, c);
}

int function(void (*func)(), ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, func);
    if(func == abc) {
        int a = va_arg(ap, int);
        func(a);
    } else if(func == one) {
        int b = va_arg(ap, int);
        int c = va_arg(ap, int);
        func(b, c);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    function(abc, 73);
    function(one, 9, 84);
}
```

Or change your sub-functions to take a va_list, then pass it from function to the sub-function.  That is probably the approach I would would take.  If want to call your sub-functions directly that write a wrapper for each that accepts a ... argument (like `printf()` and `vpritnf()` pair).  Note that this requires the sub-functions to have a fixed argument like `function()` has `func`.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to not use a variadic function at all but to use a C11 [`_Generic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) selection to call an implementation of `function` exactly matching the arguments it's supposed to relay on to `func`.

With this solution you'll get compile time checks that you've supplied compatible arguments instead of getting undefined behavior during runtime if you've made mistakes when supplying the arguments.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int function_impl_1(void(*func)(int), int a) {
    func(a);
    return 0;
}

int function_impl_2(void(*func)(int, int), int a, int b) {
    func(a, b);
    return 0;
}

#define function(X, ...) _Generic((X),               \
                      void(*)(int): function_impl_1, \
                 void(*)(int, int): function_impl_2  \
                                 )(X, __VA_ARGS__)

void abc(int a) {
    printf("abc(%d)\n", a);
}

void one(int b, int c) {
    printf("one(%d,%d)\n", b, c);
}

void two(int b, int c) {
    printf("two(%d,%d)\n", b, c);
}

int main(void) {
    function(abc, 73);
    function(one, 9, 84);
    function(two, 123, 456);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6YEYr6x8f)

Variadic macros with zero variadic arguments are problematic. There's a GNU extension, `__VA_OPT__` (from C++20), that can be used for that:

```c
#define function(X, ...) _Generic((X),               \
                     void(*)(void): function_impl_0, \
                      void(*)(int): function_impl_1, \
                 void(*)(int, int): function_impl_2  \
                                 )((X) __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__)

void zero(void) {
    puts("zero()");
}

// ...

function(zero);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qKsq48czb)

Comment: This certainly more type safe way that I would prefer. However, I think there is one tradeoff: callbacks with zero arguments won't work (`__VA_ARGS__` limitation) without compiler extensions. Unless there is some preprocessor trickery to get around that.

Comment: @user694733 Yes, with `-std=gnu11` I suppose one could use `__VA_OPT(,)__`. I added that as a note.